# How to replace default button style in visual studio extension with image?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-extensions, wpf-style

I try to remove default button style in visual studio extension and replace it with image. Exactly I try to make my button to look like image, not like button as usually do all other extensions and so on.

In preview I can see correct image and all styles are removed. But when I start debugging image just disappears.

Is there any way to fix it?

```
<UserControl x:Class="TabsGroupper.TabsGroupperToolControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:imaging="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging"
             xmlns:theming="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging"
             xmlns:util="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities"
             xmlns:catalog="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualStudio.Imaging;assembly=Microsoft.VisualStudio.ImageCatalog"
             xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit;assembly=Community.VisualStudio.Toolkit"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300"
             d:DesignWidth="300"
             Name="TabGroupperWindow" 
             FontFamily="Segoe UI">
    <Grid Background="#e8ecf4">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="IconButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/TabsGroupper;component/Resources/Delete.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="3">
            <Button Name="RemoveItemBtn" Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Tried with zero result:

- set image as content
- set background with imagebrush
- set absolute path for image
- set image build action to 'resource'.
- restarted VS
- reset of VS experimental instance

Comment: Is the TabsGroupper assembly referenced at runtime. i.e by the project of the debugged application?

Comment: @Clemens It's a current assembly where usercontrol is. And images too, but in addition they're in subfolder 'Resources'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/TabsGroupper;component/Resources/Delete.png">
```

This variant works, the problem was about the image. To make it work in properties of image **Build Action** should be set to **Resource**. And in addition if there are several images than each of should have **Build Action** as **Resource**.

Answer (score -1):

In the ControlTemplate, I tried as Image Source

```
Source="pack://application:,,,/Delete.png"
```

having the png file in the project directory and it worked for me...

Comment: This will obviously only work when the image file is a resource file in the same assembly. If it is in a referenced assembly (as apparently asked for in the question), you need to include the assembly name in the Pack URI. You understand the difference?

Comment: @tombobadil still doesn't work for me. It shows image in preview, but when I'm debugging or even I tried release version, still nothing. Empty button, that's all.